# In Flask-SQLAlchemy: How do I set check_same_thread=False in config.py?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my Config class, I want to set the check_same_thread to False as below (to avoid the error: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. .....)

```
class Config(object):  
    #------#
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///app.db?check_same_thread=False'
    #------#
```

However, in setting up my Config class of the Flask app, I followed Miguel Grinberg's Flask Mega-tutorial and set up the SQLAlchemy database as follows:

```
class Config(object): 
    #------#
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
   #------#
```

How do I integrate the set the check_same_thread to False in the above case?
Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the answer that worked for my question was:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
    'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db'))+'?check_same_thread=False'
```

Note that the '?check_same_thread=False' part should be added to both cases on either side of the or.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
class Config(object): 
    #------#
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db') + '?check_same_thread=False'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
   #------#
```